# An address of a website deployed using Tomcat and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web

I'm trying to run a website using Tomcat and Eclipse. I created a Dynamic Web Project, I configured web.xml file and I also used Maven. In a directory src/main/webapp I put an index.html file. I also made a simple REST service in the same project. So this REST service is working for me (for example, when I put "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/rest/item" in an address bar. But what is the address that I should write to get an access to a website I put in a webapp folder? I thought "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/" should be working, but it's not.

Comment: In your web.xml have you mapped index.html as your welcome file?

Comment: I tried but it didn't help. Anyway, I think it all worked when I was using Glassfish, but it's not with Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your setup, try "http://localhost:8080/index.html".  Do you have a context path called 'RESTfulService' setup?

Do you have a `context` element listed in your `server.xml`?  If so, what does it say?

Comment: Sadly, "http://localhost:8080/index.html" is not working either (404). I don't have a context element in it. 
In my web.xml I got 
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
In my pom.xml file I got  <finalName>RESTfulService</finalName>
in build element and I think it's what makes "http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/rest/item" work.

Comment: How are you launching your app?  Is it a packaged war file that you are deploying or running from within eclipse?  How do you have Tomcat configured in Eclipse?  Are you using the WebContent folders at all?  Do you have m2e-wtp or m2eclipse-wtp installed?

Comment: I run it within Eclipse (Project -> run as -> run on server). How should I have it configured - what should I pay attention to? WebContent is not used by me. Yes I got these installed.

Comment: I presume, of course, that you have Maven enabled on the project.  What is the server configuration set up as?  When I try to do run as->run on server, Eclipse creates for me a folder called "Servers" in which I have my Tomcat config files.  One file is server.xml and another is context.xml.  Is that the server.xml file that you checked?  By default, I believe that Eclipse assigns the project name as the context path.  Is your eclipse project called "RESTfulService"?

Comment: BTW - did you try the full path?  `http://localhost:8080/RESTfulService/index.html`

Comment: Yes, Maven is enabled. Yea, I checked something else, my mistake. So in server.xml I got '<Context docBase="Promo" path="/RESTfulService" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:Promo"/></Host>' 
and to Eric B.: yes, I tried it too.

Comment: Can you edit your original post and include your full web.xml please?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. Anyway, I got it all work....but to be honest I have no idea what was the thing that actually helped. I guess it was some build configuration iin pom file. Still, thank you for your help!